# CUPS libusbx-devel is needed error when trying to build cups-1.7.1 from source

Tags: compiling, usb, cups

I have been trying to build CUPS 1.7.1 on RHEL 5.6 using

```
$ sudo rpmbuild -ta ./cups-1.7.1-source.tar.bz2
```

and was getting:

```
error: Failed build dependencies:
        libusbx-devel is needed by cups-1.7.1-1.x86_64
```

I've since found this CUPS STR 4336 (https://www.cups.org/str.php?L4336) that described the same issue, with the comment on it to use `--without-libusb1` build option. So I tried running:

```
sudo rpmbuild -ta ./cups-1.7.1-source.tar.bz2 --without-libusb1
```

but now getting:

```
--without-libusb1: unknown option
```

Any ideas how to get it to build and/or what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch you're trying to pass to `rpmbuild` is a switch to what you'd typically provide in a `configure` step if you were building this package from source. The details of how you want your package to build are contained in a `.spec` file which is likely inside your `.tar.gz2` file.

You could unpack the tarball and confirm its contents, looking for a `.spec` file but I suspect your issue can be resolved more simply by installing the missing library, `libusbx-devel`. So I suggest installing that first and trying your hand at running your `rpmbuild` command again.

```
$ sudo yum install libusbx-devel
```

Or perhaps it's known as this:

```
$ sudo yum install libusb-devel
```

#### OK that didn't work, now what?

So if you've attempted the above and your only course of action really is to include the missing `configure` switch here's how I would proceed.

```
$ mkdir somedir && cd somedir
$ tar jxvf /path/to/cups-1.7.1-source.tar.bz2
```

A peek inside the unpacked directory shows the `.spec` file we're looking for:

```
$ find . | grep '\.spec$'
./cups-1.7.1/packaging/cups.spec
```

If you more that file you'll notice this section at the top:

```
# Conditional build options (--with name/--without name):
#
#   dbus     - Enable/disable DBUS support (default = enable)
#   dnssd    - Enable/disable DNS-SD support (default = enable)
#   libusb1  - Enable/disable LIBUSB 1.0 support (default = enable)
#   static   - Enable/disable static libraries (default = enable)
```

So you can use these with the `--without X` switch to disable them when using `rpmbuild`, like so:

```
$ rpmbuild -ta cups-1.7.1-source.tar.bz2 --without libusb1
```

If you need to disable others just add additional `--without X` switches:

```
$ rpmbuild -ta cups-1.7.1-source.tar.bz2 --without libusb1 --without dbus
```

#### References

- [Passing conditional parameters into a rpm build](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/conditionalbuilds.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved by:

```
# rpmbuild -ta cups-1.7.1-source.tar.bz2 --without dbus --without libusb1
```

https://www.cups.org/software.php#RPM

Note: I am using CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Comment: Thanks, didn't have to use --without dbus at all, just --without libusb1 option worked. The typo in the CUPS STR comment threw me off. Thanks for the help!